# Is this a good practice to rename and reinclude std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++

The code is as following

```
// in ptr.h
#pragma once
#include <memory>
template<class T> using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
```

So every time I use std::unique_ptr, I include "ptr.h" and use it as Ptr. Is this a good practice?

Comment: You forgot the `=`, and I think it's unnecessary overhead.

Comment: A suggestion: it's not a good practice to use `#pragma once`, *especially if you write portable code*.

Comment: Sure. It makes it much harder for maintainers to figure out what your code is doing, so it increases your job security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of thing only hurts readability. The odds are higher that the average C++ programmer will know what a `unique_ptr` is before they know what your notion of `Ptr` is. Moreover I can google the former and not the latter.

Comment: Ptr is short and the user can check its definition like a code using its own classes.

Comment: @user1899020: Anything can be checked, given enough time. The question is whether you're *helping* anyone (but yourself). Remember that code is very cheap to write, but extremely expensive to read.

Comment: @user1899020 it gets even more confusing when some dummy like me comes to work on your code and uses `unique_ptr` instead of `Ptr`. Now your code is doubly confusing.

Comment: @user1899020: Are you asking a question  or making a statement? This style of code is terrible, sorry. Who cares if it's short, you only type it once. You read it over and over. I want to read what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your requirements have changed and decided to use `std::share_ptr`. You would naturally do:

```
template<class T> using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
```

OK! Great! No change in your code that uses `Ptr`. But `std::shared_ptr` is semantically different from `std::unique_ptr`. When some unknowing programmer who doesn't know of the change continues to think that `Ptr` is still `std::unique_ptr`... kaboom!

One thing I learned is that it is important not to sacrifice code readability just for the sake of being brief.